# UITextField and @property id<UITextFieldDelegate>

Tags: objective-c, ios5, delegates, uitextfield

I have UITextField and I have

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITextFieldDelegate> delegate;
```

After pressing a done button on keybord, it should dismiss. Can someone tell how I can do it using this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dismissing of the keyboard does not happen merely by being a delegate of the `UITextField`.  Your delegate must dismiss it.

In the `viewDidLoad` in your controller you must assign the delegate, or set it up in Interface Builder:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.textField.delegate = self;
}
```

Then in your controller, implement the following delegate method.

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

//  This method gets called when you hit the enter key on the keyboard, 
//  or in this case 'DONE'.  The textfield is asking if it should put
//  a carriage return in the field.  This is our opportunity to dismiss
//  the keyboard.

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];  //  This is what hides the keyboard

    return NO;
}
```

Further reading:

[Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) - developer.apple.com
[UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) - developer.apple.com

Comment: oh, thx, but dont really understand what actually do
self.textField.delegate = self;

Comment: self.textField should be the textfield that you want to be able to dismiss the keyboard from.  You are assigning its delegate to be `self`, meaning your view controller.  Your view controller is going to become the delegate for your textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Link didEndOnExit to a method that has [self resignFirstResponder]